# Any way to have current user data always on masterpage

Tags: 2013

I've had this problem for quite some time and every time I think I've found a clever way around it, it just comes back to haunt me.

We have all kinds of things on all kinds of pages. Many of them need information about the current user. I would prefer if there was a way that could just be pre-populated on the page.

I am currently using a JSOM to request the info and stick it onto a data element on the body tag. But sometimes it is slow and doesn't load before something else on the page needs it.

Is there some way to just always have the masterpage include current user data as part of the page before it gets to the user?

**Edit to include current code**
I can't find the unminified version of the code at the moment, but this is what we are using to get back the basic stuff like user login, name, and email.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function e() {
        var e = new SP.ClientContext.get_current,
            r = e.get_web();
        u = r.get_currentUser(), e.load(u), e.executeQueryAsync(t, n)
    }

    function t() {
        $.data(document.body, "currentUser", u), $("body").trigger("userdata", {
            status: "success",
            data: u
        })
    }

    function n() {
        $("body").trigger("userdata", {
            status: "fail"
        })
    }
    var u;
    null != SP.ClientContext ? SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(e, "SP.js") : SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", null, e)
});
```

Comment: What kind of current user data ? Can you post the jsom code as well ?

Comment: In my case, the first time someone comes to my site I'm doing a sync request to get the user info (name, email, manager) and then I store them into localStorage. So next time those info are immediately available from localStorage. And after 45 seconds on a page I have an async request to update those info (in case something changed with the current user). This method will only work in a work/intranet environment

Comment: We are an on prem 2013 site, so that might work, although we do have a lot of users on IE8 so probably can't use localstorage. The part that makes me crazy is that every page has the user's name in the upper right corner. It seems like a minimal amount of user data could just be loaded on to the page and make it easier.

Comment: Instead of JSOM (which can only execute after SP.js is loaded) do it with a REST call... and ditch jQuery (which now also needs to load first)... although IE8 (which Microsoft no longer supports since january 12th **2016**) might give you some Xhr headaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UserCustomAction` `Site` `ScriptLink` will fire early on every page (except Modern Experiences).

*[links only, no need to duplicate existing documentation]*

- https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_UserCustomAction

### Disclaimer: you might need to tweak it for IE

This is the simplest bare JavaScript to get the CurrentUser

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET","/_api/web/CurrentUser", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json;odata=verbose");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (response) {
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;//no response received yet 
  if (xhr.status===200) {
      console.info(xhr);
      var currentUser=JSON.parse(xhr.response);
      console.info(currentUser);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: We are using a scriptlink on the masterpage, but sometimes the result of the request doesn't come back quickly enough for other scripts on the page.

Comment: See other comment. Your problem is not the response coming back late.. You are querying for your data way to late because it requires jQuery and SP.js be loaded first

Comment: I'm looking at that page. I don't understand what  a UserCustomAction is and where it comes from? All my googls searches for those come back with C# and VB script. My access is just at the Site Collection level. Is that something I can even do?

Comment: Doesn't SOP.RequestExecutor have to wait until SP.js loads? I'm not sure this approach would get me anywhere faster.

Comment: ?? That is AppWeb/HostWeb technology you are refering to now? But the code you shows has nothing to do with an App... Fastest is to not be dependent on jQuery or any other library. Thus JavaScript HttpRequest (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) BUT its a pain to get it working on IE9 or lower.. that is why jQuery $ajax became so popular.

Comment: The example you linked to starts executor.executeAsync(... which I can't seem to get working. And it doesn't make any sense to me because I don't know what a UserCustomAction is. I'm trying to work it out without dependencies, but the whole problem of earlier versions of IE etc.

Comment: For less techy UserCustomActions explantion see: https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage BUT you  won't gain anything compared to a ScriptLink you now have in the MasterPage as you still need to wait for SP.js and jQuery. Only when you ditch those technologies for a plain JavaScript XMLHttpRequest will you get your data sooner. Since you require IE8 support none of the code I have helps you.

Comment: I added a script, your mileage may vary on IE versions.. IE10 preferred

Comment: Thanks. I had been working my way toward something like this. With this kind of code won't I have to wait until _spPageContextInfo is on the page?  Also if I try any value other than odata=verbose, I  either get xml back or nothing at all.

Comment: Good catch.. use a property from ``document.location``.. and yes you have to do some tweaking for IE (I do not develop for anything below IE10 anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Danny's help and other references, here is the code I've got working in IE8 and IE11, Chrome, and FireFox. Haven't test it on mobile devices yet...

```
var _currentUser,xhr;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    try {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (ex) {
        xhr = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200){
            var result = JSON.parse(xhr.response || xhr.responseText);
            _currentUser = result.d || result;
        } else if (xhr.status == 400){
            console.log("not found")
        } else {
            console.log("other")
        }
    }
}
xhr.open("GET","https://<site-collection>/_api/web/currentuser",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json;odata=verbose")
xhr.send()
```

Here are a couple of gotchas that I've worked around.
 - For IE 8 you need the ActiveXObject version of the XMLHttpRequest object.
 - In IE 8 the reply comes back in the responseText object not in the response.
 - I tried using `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`, but that isn't defined for IE8, so I just went with the magic **4** when testing the readyState.

Still looking to improve it.

- I can't get anything other than **odata=verbose** to work.
- I've hard-coded the sitecollection url. I get an error if I try to use `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`.

Comment: Don't worry too much about ``verbose``, you only get 300 Bytes more. It does matter when you are going to call an endpoint and you get back loads of Items in a resultset. Also note that ``verbose`` versus ``nometadata`` gives you back a different resultset structure. And you can do without the path and only call ``"/_api/web/currentuser"``